# How could I automate after effect video on RSS feed update

Tags: automation, adobe-after-effects

I have an RSS feed with a text and an image.
I need to trigger this RSS on update and use the image and text inside the after effect composition, start the exportation, and upload on the Internet.

It's not strictly a graphic problem but I think this community is the only one who came out with a solution.